# Passing an Integer with Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have following exception

```
public class MyException extends SecurityException{
      public MyException( String s ) { super( s ) ; }
}
```

where `SecurityException` is `java.lang.SecurityException`.

whenever I throw `MyException("Message");`, I can get the message.

Now, in `MyException` I want to pass an `integer` value with `MyException` and access that `integer` where I am catching this `MyException`.

How do I do that ?

Comment: Exception classes aren't some mystical voodoo magic - they're objects just like anything else. Do it in the same way that you would do it for any other type of object.

Comment: Ohh yes @JonK  I had not seen any such exceptions so I was assuming it would be difficult. Thanks, next time I would approach problems in that easy way mindset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class MyException extends SecurityException{
  private int i;
  public MyException(String s, int i) { 
     super(s);
     this.i = i;
  }

  public int getI() { return i; }
}
```

Comment: I have this `catch(Exception e)` where `e` would be `MyException` but now if i see i can only have `java.lang.Exception's` methods not `getValue()`

Comment: If you want to pass values within your exception, then in your code you should catch your own exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a member variable in MyException class and use it at catch point. Something like -

```
public class MyException extends SecurityException{
  private Integer value;
  public MyException( Integer n, String s ) { 
       super(s) ;
       value = n;
  }
  public Integer getValue() {
       return value;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have this `catch(Exception e)` where `e` would be `MyException` but now if i see i can only have `java.lang.Exception's` methods not `getValue()`

Comment: You need to catch MyException specifically, not generic class Exception.